# Peugeot 206: Dash and clock backlights stopped working

Tags: lights, interior, peugeot

I've double checked all internal and external fuses I can find, that being panel next to the battery and panel under steering wheel. I adjusted wires on my head unit but then when I put it all back after a little while the dashboard lights stop working.

I had a quick look at the wiring but unless anyway has any suggestions I'll have to try pulling more of the dash apart to find where the problem lies =(

Answer (score 3):

Turned out when I whacked the dimmer switch for the dash lights and the speedometer etc section came to life (back-light came on). Clock is still not working but if I spend a bit more time on that I should be able establish what's wrong, I may have actually blown the back-light bulb for it. (I will update)

Comment: did you manage to fix this?

Comment: Got rid of the car, don't think I ever solved it

Answer (score 2):

It's real easy to pinch a wire when working in the dash area.  If not a short that blows a fuse, a wire may have gotten cut clean through.